# Occasional AngularJS error when directive is compiling

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I have an AngularJS directive that renders into a custom social share widget.  Out of about 10,000 page views per day, around 1 or 2 of those times, Angular errors out after starting to compile the directive. This leaves the raw HTML partial in the DOM, visible to the user.

I only came to know of this error because it was reported by several users.  I can't reproduce it, but I have devised some informative logging which shows that it is occurring.

Each time this has occurred:

- Browser is always Chrome
- OS is Mac or Windows
- Angular starts the compile phase, but fails before starting post link
- Angular reports an error during the compile phase, but the 'exception' object passed to the '$exceptionHandler' service is always null.
- No other JavaScript errors are reported

This error is occurring for some of the same IPs across multiple days.

Has anyone out there had a similar issue?

**Edit**

Here's my code...

JavaScript:

```
(function () {

  angular.module('common', []);

  angular.module('common')
    .filter('encodeURIComponent', function () {
      return window.encodeURIComponent;
    });

  function configure($provide) {

    // Pass all Angular errors to Loggly
    $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function ($delegate) {
      return function exceptionHandlerDecorator(exception, cause) {
        $delegate(exception, cause);
        _LTracker.push({
          'error': 'angularError',
          'app': 'shareCounts',
          'err': exception,
          'element': cause
        });
      };
    });

  }

  angular.module('common')
    .config(['$provide', configure]);

  function configure($provide) {

    // Defines available share options as well as behaviors of the share popup windows
    function shareLinksConfig() {
      return {
        'facebook': {
          width: 670,
          height: 200,
          urlBase: 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?',
          shareParamPre: 'u=',
          msgParamPre: '',
          mediaParamPre: '',
          addParams: ''
        },
        'twitter': {
          width: 550,
          height: 420,
          urlBase: 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?',
          shareParamPre: 'url=',
          msgParamPre: '&text=',
          mediaParamPre: ''
        },
        'googlePlus': {
          width: 600,
          height: 600,
          urlBase: 'https://plus.google.com/share?',
          shareParamPre: 'url=',
          msgParamPre: '',
          mediaParamPre: '',
          addParams: ''
        },
        'linkedIn': {
          width: 600,
          height: 400,
          urlBase: 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?',
          shareParamPre: 'url=',
          msgParamPre: '',
          mediaParamPre: '',
          addParams: '&mini=true'
        },
        'pinterest': {
          width: 750,
          height: 320,
          urlBase: 'https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?',
          shareParamPre: 'url=',
          msgParamPre: '&description=',
          mediaParamPre: '&media=',
          addParams: ''
        },
        'email': {
          width: 0,
          height: 0,
          urlBase: '',
          shareParamPre: '',
          msgParamPre: '',
          mediaParamPre: '',
          addParams: ''
        }
      };
    }
    $provide.factory('shareLinksConfig', shareLinksConfig);

  }

  angular.module('common')
    .config(['$provide', configure]);

  function ShareLinksController($scope, shareLinksService) {
    sendToLoggly.push("A \"ShareLinksController\" started constructing...");
    sendToLoggly.push("...and the $scope is typeof...");
    sendToLoggly.push(typeof $scope);

    var vm = this;

    vm.share = function ($event, shareVia) {
      if (shareVia !== 'email') {
        $event.preventDefault();
        // console.log($scope.mediaUrl);
        shareLinksService.openPopUp(shareVia, $scope.shareUrl, $scope.shareMsg, $scope.mediaUrl);
      }

      // Tell Google Analytics share link was clicked
      shareLinksService.pushGAEvent($scope.analyticsLocation, shareVia, $scope.shareUrl);
    };

    $scope.shareLinksShown = true; // Initialized to true, but then this gets set to false in the directive's link function if slideIn is true
    vm.toggle = function ($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      $scope.shareLinksShown = !$scope.shareLinksShown;
    };

    sendToLoggly.push("...and controller finished constructing.");
  }

  angular.module('common')
    .controller('ShareLinksController', ["$scope", "shareLinksService",
                ShareLinksController]);

  function fuShareLinks($http, shareLinksConfig, testRenderingService) {

    function compile() {

      sendToLoggly.push("A \"fuShareLinks\" directive started compiling...");

      testRenderingService.testShareCounts();

      return function postLink(scope) {
        sendToLoggly.push("A \"fuShareLinks\" directive started postLinking...");

        function Settings(shareVia, slideInDir, slideToggleLabel, colorized, showCounts) {
          var self = this,
            prop,
            splitArray;


          /* --------
             ShareVia
             --------
             Comma separated list of ways to share
             Accepted options are: 'facebook, twitter, googlePlus, linkedIn, pinterest, email' */

          // Copy the properties from the config and initialize to false
          self.shareVia = {};
          for (prop in shareLinksConfig) {
            if (shareLinksConfig.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
              self.shareVia[prop] = false;
            }
          }
          if (typeof shareVia === 'string') {
            splitArray = shareVia.split(',');
          } else {
            splitArray = [];
          }
          // Check each value of splitArray, if it is in possible share options, 
          // set that option to true.
          angular.forEach(splitArray, function (value) {
            // Clean up 'value' a bit by removing spaces
            value = value.trim();
            if (value.length > 0) {
              if (self.shareVia.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
                self.shareVia[value] = true;
              }
            }
          });


          /* --------
             Slide In
             --------
             The slide-in functionality is activated by passing a value to 'slideInDir'.
             Accepted values are 'left' or 'down' (case insensitive)
             The 'slideToggleLabel' can be any string, if empty, it defaults to 'Share'. */
          self.slideIn = {
            direction: '',
            label: 'Share'
          };
          if (typeof slideInDir === 'string') {
            slideInDir = slideInDir.toUpperCase();
          }
          switch (slideInDir) {
          case 'LEFT':
            self.slideIn.direction = 'left';
            break;
          case 'DOWN':
            self.slideIn.direction = 'down';
            break;
          }
          if (typeof slideToggleLabel === 'string') {
            self.slideIn.label = slideToggleLabel;
          }


          /* ---------
             Colorized
             ---------
             'true', 'yes', or 'colorized' (case insensitive) -- results in true
             defaults to false */
          self.colorized = false;
          if (typeof colorized === 'string') {
            colorized = colorized.toUpperCase();
          }
          switch (colorized) {
          case 'TRUE':
            self.colorized = true;
            break;
          case 'YES':
            self.colorized = true;
            break;
          case 'COLORIZED':
            self.colorized = true;
            break;
          }


          /* -----------
             Show Counts
             -----------
             'true', 'yes', or 'show' (case insensitive) -- results in true
             defaults to false */
          self.showCounts = false;
          if (typeof showCounts === 'string') {
            showCounts = showCounts.toUpperCase();
          }
          switch (showCounts) {
          case 'TRUE':
            self.showCounts = true;
            break;
          case 'YES':
            self.showCounts = true;
            break;
          case 'SHOW':
            self.showCounts = true;
            break;
          }

        }

        scope.settings = new Settings(
          scope.shareVia,
          scope.slideInDir,
          scope.slideToggleLabel,
          scope.colorized,
          scope.showCounts
        );
        // Initally hide the share links, if they are set to toggle
        if (scope.settings.slideIn.direction !== '') {
          scope.shareLinksShown = false;
        }

        function ShareCounts(shareVia) {
          var self = this;

          angular.forEach(shareVia, function (value, name) {
            self[name] = 0;
          });

          $http.get(
            '/local/social-share-counts/?url=' +
              encodeURIComponent(scope.shareUrl)
          ).success(function (data) {
            /* Check for share counts in the returned data.

               Must use consistent naming for the social networks
               from shareLinksConfig properties all the way to the
               JSON data containting the counts. 

               Expected JSON format:
               {
                "twitter": {
                  "count": 42, 
                  "updated": "2015-03-25T15:13:48.355422"
                }, 
                "facebook": {
                  "count": 120, 
                  "updated": "2015-03-25T15:13:47.470778"
                }
               }
            */
            angular.forEach(shareVia, function (value, name) {
              if (data[name] && data[name]["count"]) {
                self[name] = data[name]["count"];
              }
            });
          }).error(function (data, status) {
            sendToLoggly.push("HTTP Response " + status);
          });

        }

        // If showing share counts, get the counts from the specified networks
        if (scope.settings.showCounts) {
          scope.shareCounts = new ShareCounts(scope.settings.shareVia);
        }

        sendToLoggly.push("...and directive finished postLinking.");
      };

      sendToLoggly.push("...and directive finished compiling.");
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        shareVia: '@',
        shareUrl: '@',
        shareMsg: '@',
        mediaUrl: '@',
        analyticsLocation: '@',
        slideInDir: '@',
        slideToggleLabel: '@',
        colorized: '@',
        showCounts: '@'
      },
      controller: 'ShareLinksController',
      controllerAs: 'shrLnksCtrl',
      templateUrl: '/angular-partials/common.share-links.html',
      compile: compile
    };

  }

  angular.module('common')
    .directive('fuShareLinks', ['$http', 'shareLinksConfig', 'testRenderingService', fuShareLinks])

    .factory('testRenderingService', function () {
      var timerId = null;
      function evalShareRender() {
        var renderError = (-1 < $('em.ng-binding')
          .text()
          .indexOf('{{'));

        if (renderError) {
          console.error('RENDER ERROR');
          _LTracker.push({
            'error': 'rendering',
            'app': 'shareCounts',
            'statusMsgs': sendToLoggly,
            'userAgent': navigator.userAgent
          });
        }
      }
      return {
        testShareCounts: function () {
          if (!timerId) {
            timerId = window.setTimeout(evalShareRender, 5000);
          }
        }
      };
    });

  function shareLinksService(shareLinksConfig) {

    function openPopUp(shareVia, shareUrl, shareMsg, mediaUrl) {
      var width,
        height,
        urlBase,
        shareParamPre,
        msgParamPre,
        mediaParamPre,
        addParams,
        popUpUrl;

      width = shareLinksConfig[shareVia].width;
      height = shareLinksConfig[shareVia].height;

      urlBase = shareLinksConfig[shareVia].urlBase;
      shareParamPre = shareLinksConfig[shareVia].shareParamPre;
      msgParamPre = shareLinksConfig[shareVia].msgParamPre;
      mediaParamPre = shareLinksConfig[shareVia].mediaParamPre;
      addParams = shareLinksConfig[shareVia].addParams;

      popUpUrl = encodeURI(urlBase);
      popUpUrl += encodeURI(shareParamPre);
      popUpUrl += encodeURIComponent(shareUrl);
      if (msgParamPre && shareMsg) {
        popUpUrl += encodeURI(msgParamPre);
        popUpUrl += encodeURIComponent(shareMsg);
      }
      if (mediaParamPre && mediaUrl) {
        popUpUrl += encodeURI(mediaParamPre);
        popUpUrl += encodeURIComponent(mediaUrl);
      }
      popUpUrl += encodeURI(addParams);

      // Open the social share window
      window.open(popUpUrl, '_blank', 'width=' + width + ',height=' + height);
    }


    function pushGAEvent(analyticsLocation, shareVia, shareUrl) {

      function capitalize(firstLetter) {
        return firstLetter.toUpperCase();
      }

      var gaEventAction = shareVia;
      gaEventAction = gaEventAction.replace(/^[a-z]/, capitalize);
      gaEventAction += ' - Clicked';

      _gaq.push([
        '_trackEvent',
        analyticsLocation + ' - SocialShare',
        gaEventAction,
        shareUrl
      ]);
    }

    return {
      openPopUp: openPopUp,
      pushGAEvent: pushGAEvent
    };

  }

  angular.module('common')
    .factory('shareLinksService', ['shareLinksConfig', shareLinksService]);

}());
```

HTML:

```
<div class="share-links-wrapper" ng-class="{ 'right': settings.slideIn.direction === 'left', 'center': settings.slideIn.direction === 'down' }" ng-cloak>
  <a href="#" class="toggle" ng-show="settings.slideIn.direction != ''" ng-click="shrLnksCtrl.toggle($event)">
    <i class="fuicon-share"></i>{{ settings.slideIn.label }}
  </a>
  <div class="share-links" ng-class="{ 'share-links-colorized': settings.colorized }" ng-show="shareLinksShown">
    <ul>
      <li ng-show="settings.shareVia.facebook">
        <a href="#" ng-click="shrLnksCtrl.share($event, 'facebook')" 
           class="fuicon-hex-facebook">
        </a>
        <em ng-show="settings.showCounts &amp;&amp; shareCounts.facebook > 0">
          {{ shareCounts.facebook }}
        </em>
      </li>
      <li ng-show="settings.shareVia.twitter">
        <a href="#" ng-click="shrLnksCtrl.share($event, 'twitter')" 
           class="fuicon-hex-twitter">
        </a>
        <em ng-show="settings.showCounts &amp;&amp; shareCounts.twitter > 0">
          {{ shareCounts.twitter }}
        </em>
      </li>
      <li ng-show="settings.shareVia.googlePlus">
        <a href="#" ng-click="shrLnksCtrl.share($event, 'googlePlus')" 
           class="fuicon-hex-googleplus">
        </a>
        <em ng-show="settings.showCounts &amp;&amp; shareCounts.googlePlus > 0">
          {{ shareCounts.googlePlus }}
        </em>
      </li>
      <li ng-show="settings.shareVia.linkedIn">
        <a href="#" ng-click="shrLnksCtrl.share($event, 'linkedIn')" 
           class="fuicon-hex-linkedin">
        </a>
        <em ng-show="settings.showCounts &amp;&amp; shareCounts.linkedIn > 0">
          {{ shareCounts.linkedIn }}
        </em>
      </li>
      <li ng-show="settings.shareVia.pinterest &amp;&amp; mediaUrl">
        <a href="#" ng-click="shrLnksCtrl.share($event, 'pinterest')"
           class="fuicon-hex-pinterest">
        </a>
        <em ng-show="settings.showCounts &amp;&amp; shareCounts.pinterest > 0">
          {{ shareCounts.pinterest }}
        </em>
      </li>
      <li ng-show="settings.shareVia.email">
        <a href="mailto:?subject={{ shareMsg | encodeURIComponent }}
                 &amp;body={{ shareUrl | encodeURIComponent }}" 
           ng-click="shrLnksCtrl.share($event, 'email')"
           class="fuicon-hex-email">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: atleast show us the related directive code / give link to the website

Comment: Code please, and also would help you to know what chrome extensions they are using.

Comment: Post the code like said before and if nobody got an answer post an issue to angular github repository. It could be OS or Browser specific or more specific !

Answer (score 0):

Not had such an issue, but as its so infrequent could you make it reload the page?

Also, do you know about ng-cloak? it can be useful to hide the raw stuff :)

Could it be a race condition?

Comment: Seems like if it were a race condition that it would occur more often than 1 in 10000, could be though.

Comment: I would agree but I have seen such odds 

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, but I have been using ng-cloak : /